# MongoId combined uniqueness index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, validates-uniqueness-of

I have three models

```
class Org
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :org_groups
end

class OrgGroup
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :org
  has_and_belongs_to_many :humans
end

class Human
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
end
```

One Human can be in many Org, but only in one OrgGroup.

I need set uniqueness index for Human in Org.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a unique index in the mongodb, you can do like this:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name
  field :last_name

  index({ first_name: 1, last_name: 1 }, { unique: true })
end
```

And the docs are here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-indexes/

Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that will be call by a callback.
See [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html) for callbacks.

You can simply raise something from this method if your conditions are not respected.

Ask if you need a sample.

Comment: this solution very good for model layer. Thanks!
Can I do this on MongoDB layer? I use single db with many services, good idea create index in MongoDB but I don't know as

Comment: I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: I need create uniqueness index in MongoDB, not in Mongoid

Comment: Still not sure of what you mean. Mongoid is a wrapper of MongoDB for your ruby environment. It deals itself with fields creation etc. However, if you want to create an index on a field (for quicker search) in one of your models, you can check this documentation: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html